# ios swift: Tableview "un"-checkmark cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I do this, when I know, that there is data I can checkmark:

```
if (self.selectedLessonObject != nil){
    if(lessons["name"] as String == selectedLessonObject["name"] as String){
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
}
```

Within `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I do:

```
// update the checkmark for the current row
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
```

What I can't figure out yet is how to deselect FIRST the old cell before I select the chosen new cell?

How can I save the selected row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and access it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to unselect it?

Thanks!!

EDIT:

When I try this:

```
var lastSelectedRow: NSIndexPath? = nil
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if (self.selectedLessonObject != nil){
            if(lessons.objectId == selectedLessonObject.objectId){
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                lastSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

            }else{
                cell.accessoryType = .None
            }
        }
println("selected: \(lastSelectedRow)")
```

I get a nil output.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` the I thought about this:

```
// Other row is selected - need to deselect it
// catch the previous selected row
var oldcell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(lastSelectedRow!)
oldcell?.accessoryType = .None
```

But I am not able to catch the current row from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select new row in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` check if the new property is not nill and if so get cell by calling

```
if let last = lastSelectedRow {
    let oldSelectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(last)
    oldSelectedCell.accessoryType = .None
}
lastSelectedRow = indexPath
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check if the new property is not nill and is equal indexPath and checkmark otherwise uncheckmark:

```
if let last = lastSelectedRow {
    if (self.selectedLessonObject != nil){
        if(lessons.objectId == selectedLessonObject.objectId && last == indexPath){
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    } else{
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }
} else{
    if (self.selectedLessonObject != nil){
        if(lessons.objectId == selectedLessonObject.objectId){
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            lastSelectedRow = indexPath

        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1555112 what have you tried? can you post your code? you have to add the code to both cellForRow and didSelectRow methods.

Comment: @user1555112 please see my amended answer.

Comment: Where and as what type needs `lastSelectedRow ` to be set? As right now I never reach the if construct, as the var is set to nil at the right beginning.

Comment: @user1555112 I edited my past again. I cannot see all of the code and it's difficult to provide you the solution. If you use checkmark just for mark selectedLessonObject.objectId you can add value in didSelectRow to that object and reload the table view in this scenario you don't even need lastSelectedRow.

Comment: I got now right, thanks so much! That all helped me a lot!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can save indexPath or row of your selected cell. Or you can try to get it from:

```
tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lastSelectedRow = indexPath
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark

        if selected.count > 0{
            if selected.containsObject(lastSelectedRow!.row){
                if cell!.accessoryType == .Checkmark{
                    cell!.accessoryType = .None
                    selected.removeObject(lastSelectedRow!.row)
                }else{
                    cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                }
            }else{
                selected.addObject(lastSelectedRow!.row)
            }
        }else{
            selected.addObject(lastSelectedRow!.row)
        }
```

Comment: var selected: NSMutableArray!